# How to stick div on top of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just want to stick the div on top of the page

if someone scrolls the page then the green div `stickdiv` should be automatically stick in the top

```
var left = document.getElementsByClassName("stickdiv");

for( var i = 0;i<left.length;i++){
var stop = (left[0].offsetTop);

window.onscroll = function (e) {
var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
    if (scrollTop >= stop) {
     left.className += " stick"; //adding a class name
    } else {
        className = '';
    }

}
}
```

why adding stick class on the div does not working - https://jsfiddle.net/kzk5qab2/1/

I just want to stick the div at top like yellow div on this - http://jsfiddle.net/qc4NR/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have looped into the array of `left` items, but forget to reference the array index when trying to add the class name to the element.

```js
var left = document.getElementsByClassName("stickdiv");

for (var i = 0; i < left.length; i++) {
  var stop = (left[0].offsetTop);

  window.onscroll = function(e) {
    var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
    // left.offsetTop;
    if (scrollTop >= stop) {
      // get array item by index
      left[0].classList.add('stick'); //adding a class name
    } else {
      // get array item by index
      left[0].classList.remove('stick');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.stickdiv {
  height: 50vh!important;
  width: 100vh!important;
  background-color: green!important;
}
.stick {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 0
}
#right {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: red;
}
.des {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="des"></div>
<div class="stickdiv"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

You don't even need to loop if you select the item directly, as in the following:

```
var left = document.querySelector(".stickdiv");
var stop = (left.offsetTop);

window.onscroll = function(e) {
  var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
  // left.offsetTop;
  if (scrollTop >= stop) {
    left.classList.add('stick'); //adding a class name
  } else {
    left.classList.remove('stick');
  }
}
```

Comment: @seemly it benefits future users to not have to leave the site to see a working example. That's why I converted your JSFiddle to a Stack Snippet.

Comment: I would like to point out, and this more for the OP than anyone, that the for loop isn't necessary.

Comment: @hungerstar agreed. Code snippet added as you were typing your comment. =)

Comment: I don't know how helping future visitors clouds anything. If JSFiddle goes down or becomes defunct you still have a working example with a Stack Snippet. The Stack Snippet cleanly divides HTML, CSS and JS into it's own regions for clear readability. If anything, point out the main change and include a collapsed Stack Snippet afterwords.

Comment: @Anjali if this answer fixed your issue, please be sure to accept the answer. =)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what browsers you need to support, you don't necessarily need JS for this.

```
.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/afisher88/pen/xJaxoP

Browser support for position sticky: https://caniuse.com/#search=position%3A%20sticky